# Unable to read OWL axioms

Tags: java, ontology, owl-api

I am reading the attached [university-bench](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13KZKd9zTqkvCi1o94hq2WjHua3Z4QQlv/view?usp=sharing) ontology file (which I generated from UBA1.7 lubm) in java using owlapi. But it is not reading any axiom like subclass etc. And it is also not giving me any error. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. The below code I used to retrieve the subclass axioms from this ontology but it return me nothing/ blank output. I wanted to output subclass, disjoint class, sub property, disjoint property, anonymous superclass axioms. but currently I am unable to get anything out from the ontology.

When I use the ontology which is created by me using protege. The below code works fine. But when i try to execute the ontology generated from UBA1.7 it gives me nothing.

```
public static void axioms(File ontology) throws OWLOntologyCreationException {
        OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(ontology);
        OWLDataFactory df = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
        
        for (final OWLSubClassOfAxiom subClasse : ontology.getAxioms(AxiomType.SUBCLASS_OF))
        {
            if (subClasse.getSuperClass() instanceof OWLClass && subClasse.getSubClass() instanceof OWLClass)
            {
                System.out.println(subClasse.getSubClass()  + " extends " + subClasse.getSuperClass());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add exactly what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Comment: @peer I have added it.

Comment: Thanks, Please print the size of `ontology.getAxioms(AxiomType.SUBCLASS_OF)` and if it is not empty add an else block in the for loop and print   `subClasse.getSubClass()` and `subClasse.getSuperClass()` there as well, so you know more about the elements

Comment: @peer it gives me the size 0 but there are subclasses in the ontology as I have attached the ontology file in the question. I have also added the else but nothing works.

Comment: I can't say much about owl. General advice: 
1) make a [MRE] cut your onotology file way down, I think you can cut it down enough that it fits in the question. 
2) get rid of the for loop if there are no elements
3) try different parameters for `ontology.getAxioms`